# export to epub format in php

Tags: php, export, epub, ibooks

Does anyone know of a php class that can create/export ePub files?

I have a book stored in a mysql database and I wish to publish it as an ePub format book?

It's a very basic book, simple text and chapters, and a few images.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps writing one? With http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPub you should get results quite fast. It's just little more than a bunch of zipped HTML files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [ePubExport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epubexport/) project or get an idea from its source code.

> ePubExport is a Mediawiki extension
>   for export wiki pages in epub format
>   for offline reading in supported
>   electronic readers or tablets.

Also have a look at award-winning class [EPub](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6115-PHP-Create-ebook-in-EPUB-format-for-Apple-iPad-.html)

> This class can be used to create
>   create an ebook in EPUB format for
>   Apple iPad and other ebook readers.
>
> It can set the ebook details like the
>   author, publisher, comments, etc., as
>   well the ebook chapter data.
>
> The class builds an archive with all
>   the ebook information and serves the
>   ebook archive for download or returns
>   it as a string.

**More Resources/Libraries:**

- [OPL's EPUB library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary/)
- [on-the-fly epub creation](http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=44907)

Answer (score 4):

Epub is just an archive, like zip or tar. If you want to create an epub file with php from scratch, you have to create separate html-files and a few xml-files with the correct information. Then you should combine them in an archive, it's actually just a zip-archive. It's a little bit work, but it's not very difficult to do with php.

Creating a zip: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

For XML, it's the simplest to create just the tags you need, it's simple to build it with the correct output.

So:

1) Create html and xml-files and save them temporarily on your server.

2) Create a zip archive with the correct files on your server.

3) Let the user download the archive with the extension .epub.

Good luck!