# Get data from mysql and display in .epub format using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, converters, epub, data-conversion

I want to `get data from mysql and display in .epub format using php`, since am very new php (Codeigniter) & don't know about `ePub (one of eBook format)`, please can some one help me to achieve this. What is the logic or the process need to follow.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Step 1) Google "php format data .epub" & see what's already on this site and elsewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321568/export-to-epub-format-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You should output the data of the SQL database into XHTML files, and also keep record of which XHTML files you've written. With such output, you could use an EPUB creator tool manually or call it automatically. Since PHP is able to create zip files, all of this can be done within PHP. In case your question is still unsolved and you want such a PHP based EPUB creation software (or a workflow with a separate EPUB creator tool to call), just let me know, I would probably develop such a solution (licensed under GNU AGPL).